# How to log data into Blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

A very practical question in Blockchain: How does one actually go about putting data into the blockchain, i.e. the digital ledger used by Bitcoin? Is there an API/SDK/open source library one can use? Does it require a wallet? What is the data size limits? Does it cost money? Can anyone provide some pointers in this area?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you'll probably get an answer on the bitcoin SE site, eg: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39347/how-to-store-data-on-the-blockchain

Comment: If you want a Bitcoin specific question, go for Bitcoin SE. But in general, you can also check out how to store up to 45kB data on the Ethereum blockchain: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1106/87